# Migrating from Spring Boot 1.5.21 to 2.7.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am migrating my application from Spring Boot 1.5.21 to 2.7.1. and Java from 8 to 17.

I am facing issues with displaying error message from controller.
Existing Spring Boot controller does not accept any media type apart from `application/json`. It is supposed to throw a 415 unsupported media type exception for all input other than JSON.

The request looks this: `http://localhost:8080/test/ghsahgs/submitinfo`. I am passing a body which is not JSON and expect this controller to throw an error.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/test")
public class SubmissionController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/{name}/submitinfo",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity submit(@PathVariable("name") final String name, @RequestBody final String data) {
```

This works as expected and throws 415 error but what happens is that instead of getting this massage in Postman, I get HTML login page. This is because of `WebSecurityConfig` which looks like below.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/Demo/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/Demo/login")
                .usernameParameter(USERNAME)
                .passwordParameter(PASSWORD)
                .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/Demo/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies(JSESSIONID)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage(ACCESS_DENIED);
}
    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/test/**");
    }
}
```

Seems like controller throws the exception but `webSecurityConfig` does not know how to handle it?

StackTrace:

```
2022-07-06 05:53:40 36119 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet correlationId= sessionid=E0DC60ECB2E5D0A87E6E8A25131279DD  - Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
2022-07-06 05:53:40 36121 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.web.FilterChainProxy correlationId= sessionid=E0DC60ECB2E5D0A87E6E8A25131279DD  - Securing POST /error
2022-07-06 05:53:40 36122 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter correlationId= sessionid=E0DC60ECB2E5D0A87E6E8A25131279DD  - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-07-06 05:53:40 36123 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter correlationId= sessionid=E0DC60ECB2E5D0A87E6E8A25131279DD  - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-07-06 05:53:40 36127 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor correlationId= sessionid=E0DC60ECB2E5D0A87E6E8A25131279DD  - Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [fullyAuthenticated]
2022-07-06 05:53:40 36129 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache correlationId= sessionid=E0DC60ECB2E5D0A87E6E8A25131279DD  - Saved request http://localhost:8080/error to session
2022-07-06 05:53:40 36129 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy correlationId= sessionid=E0DC60ECB2E5D0A87E6E8A25131279DD  - Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/Demo/login
```

I need the error message to be displayed as below instead of a webpage

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2022-07-06T06:08:30.894+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/test/ghsahgs/submitinfo"
}
```

This was working in the Spring version 1.5.21 but has stopped working in the new Spring version. Also, it works, if I comment out the `configure(final HttpSecurity http)` method in the `WebSecurityConfig` class. Any body knows how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing when disabling CSRF while allowing session authentication?

Comment: This is an application which is for internal use only, it's not exposed to web.

Comment: If the application allows access to critical resources and someone from outside knows where the application is accessible internally, they could still attack it. But if not, it should be fine. You need to know what you are doing.

Comment: @sinsanarya The logs are clear: *Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [fullyAuthenticated]*. Are you loggged in?

Comment: Have you checked all the release notes and migration guides from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.7?